# Using another table field as owner field for DataStore Authentication

Tags: aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

**Which Category is your question related to?**
DataStore (GraphQL API)

**Amplify CLI Version**
7.6.23

**What AWS Services are you utilizing?**
DataStore (GraphQL API)

**Provide additional details e.g. code snippets. *Be sure to remove any sensitive data.***

I am trying to build a service where people can buy subscriptions to certain "Persons" and consume their information. I want to restrict people so that they can only access the data of a certain medium when they are subscribed to it.

Here is the basic structure:

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  personID: ID! @index(name: "byPerson")
  person: Person! @belongsTo(fields: ["personID"])
}
```

```
type Person @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @hasMany(indexName: "byPerson", fields: ["id"])
}
```

```
type Subscription @model {
  id: ID!
  personID: ID! @index(name: "byPerson")
  person: Person! @belongsTo(fields: ["personID"])
  userSub: String! // or whatever data we need to reference the user
}
```

So we have Subscriptions to Persons and Persons can have multiple posts. It is not necessary to fetch a Person if you want to fetch the Posts that a user should be able to see.

#### What should be possible:

Users should only be able to fetch the posts of the persons that they are subscribed to. There are two ways that I can think of doing but they all require me to change/update data. Since all the data is present, I am not a fan of such solutions.

#### **Solution #1**:

Add a group to each user, attach it to the post and add the user to the group as soon as he subscribed

```
type Post @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: groups, groupsField: "groups" }]) {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  personID: ID! @index(name: "byPerson")
  person: Person! @belongsTo(fields: ["personID"])
  groups: String!
}
```

Not a fan, it requires me to create a group each time a Person is created and I basically have duplicated information here with each post.

#### **Solution #2**:

Use an owner field and attach the user as soon as he subscribes

```
type Post @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "subscribers" }]) {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  personID: ID! @index(name: "byPerson")
  person: Person! @belongsTo(fields: ["personID"])
  subscribers: [String]
}
```

Not a fan as well, I need to edit all the postings as soon as a user subscribes/cancels his subscriptions. The margin of error and amount of calculations here could be huge

I have thought about using a custom resolver (no idea if that works, I don't fully understand it yet) or a custom lambda auth check. The custom lambda auth check causes some issues in the frontend with DataStore. Apparently I need to manually refresh the token for the API or something like that.

#### What do I want to do?

I would love to use the subscription userSub field as an owner field for the posts. Is that possible (with DataSync) in any way?